# how to use flutter ios fcm?

Tags: ios, flutter, image, notifications

Firebase messaging is being used.
In the case of android, the image comes out well in the notification without any restrictions, but ios does not come out in the notification.

I created and applied UNNOTification Service Extension in xcode.

But it's meaningless.

Even if you look at the contents of https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-image, it says how to send it from the server, not anything else.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

on ios it really needs a little trick, previously I also wanted to display information notifications on android running but in the case of ios it just didn't want to be active, so I used this

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Comment: Wouldn't there be two notifications?

Comment: just adjust it to trigger the condition to appear .

there will be configuration settings for ios or android.

Comment: for reference : https://www.dbestech.com/tutorials/flutter-local-notification-explained-for-ios-and-android